# bash: cd to the most recently modified child directory

Tags: bash, date, cd-command

Wondering if there's an easy and/or portable way to say "change to the most recently modified child directory". I can use `ls` and `awk` but there's probably a better way.

```
cd $( ls -ltrd */ | tail -1 | awk '{ print $8 }' )
```

I have to run a command in an "output files" directory with hundreds of subdirectories and 99% of the time I want to go to the most recently changed directory. I don't know what the names of the directories will be in advance.

Comment: Why not `cd $(ls -v1td */ | head -1)`?

Comment: Good point...I'm not as familiar with ls options as I should be...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assuming your directories don't contain any unprintable characters:

```
cd  "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"
```

(note that it will also consider symlinks to directories).

If you don't mind switching to zsh:

```
cd ./*(/om[1])
```

Or to include symlinks to directories as in the first example:

```
cd ./*(-/om[1])
```

Comment: How can I make an `alias` for it, when I make alias it doesn't always work in current directory and tries to change to the direcotry the last time was calld.

Comment: @Ahmad At a guess: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199085/bashrc-lazy-substitution

Comment: thanks, creating a function for it works

Comment: See [zsh glob qualifiers o and m](https://gist.github.com/roalcantara/5cf137f83261d8108f53019748c17222#file-1e_glob_qualifiers_sort-zsh-L19)

Answer (score 0):

Without relying on the output of `ls`, and assuming GNU coreutils:

```bsh
cd "$(stat --printf='%Y:%n\0' ./*/ | sort -zt: -k1nr | head -zn1 | cut -zd: -f2-)"
```

Comment: Note that since coreutils 9.1, `ls` supports `--zero`.

Comment: If using `bash`, you'll see something like `bash: line 1: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`. Because of the trailing NUL in there. Also note that it won't work if the name of the most recent directory ends in newline characters.

Comment: Hmm, I get the same trailing null problem with `ls --zero -dt ./*/ | head -zn1`

Comment: Yes, you'd need something like `IFS= read -rd '' newest < <(nulldelimitedoutput) && cd...` (which would also address the problem when the output is empty (worse in your fish answer; you're missing the -z to cut there as well)).

Answer (score -2):

Try this short versioned command

```
cd $(ls -t | head -n 1)
```

Comment: That only works if the most recently modified file in the current directory is of type _directory_ (or symlink to directory) and it's name doesn't contain blanks or wildcards or newlines and doesn't start with -, so it's hardly an improvement over the already accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Similarly, what has been said previously

```
cd $(ls -td <prefix for the path and file name>* | head -n 1)
```

should work as well.

Comment: Yes, this is *very* similar to what has been said before.  What value do you believe you are adding?