# bashrc lazy substitution

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias, bashrc

How does one get `~/.bashrc` aliases to **evaluate `$()` substitutions at run time**, instead of at the time that ~/.bashrc is executed (when opening a terminal)?

I run this command often enough that I would like to add an alias for it:

```
svn diff -r $(svn info | grep ^Revision | awk {'print $2'}):HEAD $(svn info | grep ^URL | awk {'print $2'}) | colordiff
```

However, when I add it to `~/.bashrc` as an alias, I see that the evaluations are hard-coded to the values they had at the time I opened the terminal:

```
$ alias
alias svnbranch='svn diff -r 178184:HEAD svn+ssh://branches/t4252 | colordiff'
```

If I open a terminal in `~` then I get errors:

```
svn: E155007: '/home/dotancohen' is not a working copy
svn: E155007: '/home/dotancohen' is not a working copy
svn: E155007: '/home/dotancohen' is not a working copy
svn: E155007: '/home/dotancohen' is not a working copy
$ alias
alias svnbranch='svn diff -r :HEAD  | colordiff'
$
```

I've tried these two variations of the alias in `~/.bashrc`, they both have the same effect (as I expected):

```
alias svnbranch="svn diff -r $(svn info | grep ^Revision | awk {'print $2'}):HEAD $(svn info | grep ^URL | awk {'print $2'}) | colordiff"
alias svnbranch="svn diff -r `svn info | grep ^Revision | awk {'print $2'}`:HEAD `svn info | grep ^URL | awk {'print $2'}` | colordiff"
```

**How does one get `~/.bashrc` aliases to evaluate `$()` substitutions at run time**?

Additionally, how would one **search for this situation in Google?** I've tried to google on "bashrc substitution", "bashrc lazy substitution", and other key phrases, but I've found nothing for what I feel should be a common enough issue to find information on.

Comment: Why does it have to be an alias? Move it to a shell script and be done with it. Most *ix type systems put `$HOME/bin` into the `PATH` if you have such a directory these days.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: You are correct, this particular instance could be a script. However, I would still like to know the answer as I do prefer aliases for other things and I'll certainly run  into this. I could generalize your question into "why does Bash support aliases when anything could be a script."

Comment: Why the downvote? **How could I improve the question?** I've provided examples, failed attempts, and even the keyphrases that I tried to google on.

Comment: @dotancohen: I think you should ask that separately. I'll give a partial answer here: `alias cdp="cd ~/projects"`. Can't do that in a shell script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) to suppress processing of special characters. You could also [backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Escape-Character) [the](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes) `$`s.

For a complex command you are probably better off using a function in any case, which doesn't require any escaping and is easier to read and edit:

```
svnbranch() {
    svn diff -r $(svn info | grep ^Revision | awk {'print $2'}):HEAD $(svn info | grep ^URL | awk {'print $2'}) | colordiff
}
```

You can define a function anywhere you could define an alias.

Comment: `awk` has a pattern space as well `awk '/^Revision/{ print ...}'`  So no need for grep in this case.