# fish: cd to the most recently modified child directory

Tags: terminal, fish

related to this post, [cd to the most recently modified child directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16631/508426)

bash `cd  "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"` 
zsh  `cd ./*(/om[1])`

changes to the most recently modified directory.

But there is no script for **fish shell**.

When used the bash code in config.fish, it shows

```
$(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(\ls)'
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: FWIW, since version 3.4.0, fish supports `$(...)` as well (which can also be used inside quoted strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you try? In particular `fish` is telling you to use `'(\ls)'`. So

```
cd (ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)
```

seems to work based on 10 seconds of experimentation.
Edit: Remove `\` character.

Comment: whoa works fine.. thank you

Comment: Note that backslash acts both as a quoting operator and escape sequence introducer in fish. `\&` is a literal `&` for instance, but `\f` is a form feed and `\n` a line feed. As `l` is not special to the shell, escaping it is not useful, and you might find that future versions of fish will treat `\l` as a new escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In fish, you cannot use `$(command)`, you have to use `(command)` instead. [More info](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.3/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions)

Also, in fish, the backslash in front of `ls` should be replaced with `command`

So to sum up, use:

```bsh
cd  (command ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in this case, @icarus's answer seems to work. but yours doesn't (maybe syntax problem or something)

Comment: yes indeed you need to remove the quotes. Note that in icarus's answer, the backslash does nothing and can be removed. If you had modified `ls` to do something else via an alias or a function, the accepted answer would not work and you'd have to use the answer here

Comment: FWIW, since version 3.4.0, fish supports `$(...)` as well (which can also be used inside quoted strings).

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
ls -dt ./*/ | read newest && cd $newest
```

Though note that it doesn't work properly with filenames that contain newline characters.

With recent versions of GNU `ls`, you can address it with:

```
ls --zero -dt ./*/ | read -z newest && cd $newest
```

Or you could do:

```
zsh -c 'print -rNC1 ./*(/om[1])' | read -z newest && cd $newest
```

Or `*(-/om[1])` to also consider symlinks to directories (and the modification time of their target) like in the `*/` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than relying on the output of `ls`, and assuming you have GNU coreutils:

```bsh
cd (stat --printf='%Y:%n\0' ./*/ | sort -zt: -k1nr | head -zn1 | cut -d: -f2-)
```

Comment: fish's command substitution splits on lines, so there's no point using NUL-delimited records unless you play with `string collect`. Better use `read -z`. You're missing the `-z` option to `cut`. You'll also want to consider what happens if there's no non-hidden directory.